# How can I sort a 2d array using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 2d array of strings

```
string [] [] myArray;
```

and I want to sort it by one of the columns.

So the data might be

```
{ "Apple", "2", "Bob" },
{ "Banana", "1", "Fred" }
```

And I want to sort it by any of those columns - I'll have an index.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like `myArray.Sort(1);`

I understand I may have to use a custom comparer. I see this as an interesting learning opportunity. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: How can you have a 2d jagged array with those strings? They seems to be 3 field (of which 1 is integer)

Comment: It's an array of arrays... so myArray[0] = ["Apple", "2", "Bob"]; ie myArray[0, 0] is Apple, 0,1 is "2", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myOrderedRows = myArray.OrderBy(row => row[columnIndex]);
```

Comment: It isn't an array at the end :-) It is an `IOrderedEnumerable`. Add a `ToArray()`

Comment: Are you satisfied if I rename the variable? ;)

Comment: Yep, same answer I was typing but was late to the party :-) `data = data.OrderBy(sub => sub[columnIndex]).ToArray();`

Comment: Sweet, thanks - I thought it was going to take a couple of hours to do this.

Comment: Even if you had to sort it manually - you need a 'couple of hours' to implement a bubblesort? ;p

Comment: Probably, I've never written a sort method myself thanks to linq... I've not encountered an actual 2d string array for ages.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.Sort(myArray, (p, q) => p[0].CompareTo(q[0]));
```

This will order the array in place (so at the end `myArray` will be sorted). LINQ `OrderBy` by comparison creates a new ordered enumerable that then you can convert to a `ToArray`.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this...

```
IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable(this T[,] arr) {
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
      yield return arr[i, j];
}
```

And then write for example:

```
int[,] data = // get data somwhere
// After 'AsEnumerable' you can use all standard LINQ operations
var res = data.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(n => n).Reverse();
```