# Sort a 2d Array of integers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I want to manually sort a 2D Array in C#. 
I am confused on what to do when the pointer is on index 0 and I need to go to the previous row.
My problem when I reach to index 0 I cant go any further and it is then out of bounds.

```
int temp3 = 25;
        bool swap = false;
        bool swap2 = false;
        long pointer = productarray[4,4];
        for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--){

            for(int j = 4; j >= 0; j--){
                int temp5 = 1;
                while(swap != true){

                    if(temp3 != temp5){
                        pointer = productarray[i,j];

                            if (pointer < productarray [i, j - temp5]) {
                                long temporary = productarray [i, j];
                                productarray [i, j] = productarray [i, j - temp5];
                                productarray [i, j - temp5] = temporary;
                                temp5 = 1;


                            } else {
                                temp5++;

                            }

                    }
                    else{
                        swap = true; //Current pointer is the greatest int
                        temp3--;
                    }
                }
                swap = false;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Its a 2d array.  do you mean on index 0,0? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Need more information...Can you provide a example?

Comment: @paqogomez I mean if Im at row 3 col 0 and i want to compare it to an element how would go through the previous rows using for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

`var myOrderedRows = myArray.OrderBy(row => row[columnIndex]);`

from [How can I sort a 2d array using Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918080/how-can-i-sort-a-2d-array-using-linq)

Comment: Using integers I would like to go in increasing order throughout the entire array

Comment: @DeVonte Don't you think creating a aggregate array first, than sorting it and than converting it back to 2D array be more efficient then what you got up there?